# Problema com o MaxJsonLength ao utilizar ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, .net, asp.net

Olá,

Estou usando ajax para construção de uma table numa aplicação, mas quando o evento é acionado, o javascript não realiza a construção do html, dando o seguinte erro:

"Erro durante a serialização ou desserialização usando JSON JavaScriptSerializer. 
  O tamanho da cadeia de caracteres ultrapassa o valor definido na propriedade 
  maxJsonLength."

Já tentei aumentar o valor do maxLength, mas não resolveu o problema. Como resolver isso?

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow Vitor. Por favor, poste um trecho do código que você já tem para termos uma ideia melhor do problema, sugiro que leia esse artigo da ajuda do site: [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo tenta assim:

```
var json = Json(new { seuRetornoAqui }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
json.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
return json;
```

Comment: Resolveu meu problema, obrigado